# Asp.Net MVC Core Telerik TreeView Text shows as undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, treeview, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-treeview

I'm having an issue with Telerik TreeView Control for Asp.Net MVC. The treeview items are showing the text as 'undefined'. 
Please see the below picture.

[image: TreeView Error]

View

```
<div class="col-md-5">
        @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeviewOrgHierarchy")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Read(read => read
                .Action("Hierarchies", "OrgHierarchy")
            )
        ).Deferred()
        )
    </div>
```

Controller

```
  public JsonResult Hierarchies(int? id)
        {
            IEnumerable<TreeViewItemViewModel> items = null;
            if(id.HasValue)
            {
                items = hierarchyService.GetChildHierarchies(id.Value).Select(x => new TreeViewItemViewModel { HasChildren = x.HasChildren, Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name });
            }
            else
            {
                var rootItem = hierarchyService.GetRootHierarchy();
                items = new List<TreeViewItemViewModel> { new TreeViewItemViewModel { Id = rootItem.Id, Name = rootItem.Name, HasChildren = rootItem.HasChildren } };
            }

            return Json(items);
        }
```

I have already tried the below, but same result.

```
.DataTextField("item.Name")
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Why, and how does this work? Without better explanation, this is little more than a comment

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue, the culprit here was the below piece of code.

```
.DataTextField("Name")
```

The Json returned from the server is as below

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Root Item","hasChildren":true}]
```

The issue here was the Field Name, the Json serializer is actually converted the field names to camelCase, "Name" to "name". And as result there were no field with name "Name"  as the JavaScript is case sensitive.
So I have changed code to

```
 .DataTextField("name")
```

and which worked for me.